# Capturing the calling class up the hierarchy in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance

**Preamble**:

What I'm after is; if a method calls the `get_typed_ancestor()` method, the class name needed to perform the operations required in `get_typed_ancestor()` is the name of the class in which the calling method is *defined*.

Passing `$this` to extract the class name fails because it will resolve to the concrete class. If the calling method is defined in an abstract class higher up the hierarchy than the concrete class of which the instance is, we get the incorrect class name.

Looking for an `instanceof static` fails for the same reason as described above.

As described below, the purpose for capturing the class name in which the method is defined, is so that `get_typed_ancestor()` can find an instance of any class derived from the class in which the calling method is defined, not just another instance of the concrete class that initiated the call stack (*hence `$this` and `static` being unsatisfactory*)

So far, passing `__CLASS__` to `get_typed_ancestor()` seems to the be the only solution thus far, as `__CLASS__` will properly resolve to the class name in which the calling method is defined, not the class name of the instance invoking the calling method.

---

**Note**:

I've included at the end of this question an example showing the working `__CLASS__` argument approach, and the failed `static` approach. If you wanna take a stab, perhaps use that as a start.

---

**Question**:

I've seen several "solutions" floating around that leverage [`debug_backtrace()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to capture the calling class of a given method or function; these however are (*as my quotation marks may suggest*) not exactly solutions as far as I'm concerned, as `debug_backtrace()` used in this manner is a hack.

Rant aside, if this hack is the only answer, then hack I shall.

Anyways; I'm working on a set of classes that act as nodes in a bottom-to-top traversable tree. Here's a class hierarchy, simplified for brevity:

```
abstract class AbstractNode{}

abstract class AbstractComplexNode extends AbstractNode{}

class SimpleNode extends AbstractNode{}

class ComplexNodeOne extends AbstractComplexNode{}

class ComplexNodeTwo extends AbstractComplexNode{}
```

Nodes may have any concrete node (*or `null`*) as a parent. Looking at `AbstractNode`:

```
abstract class AbstractNode{

    protected $_parent;

    public function get_typed_ancestor(){
        // here's where I'm working
    }

    public function get_parent(){
        return $this->_parent;
    }

}
```

The method `get_typed_ancestor()` is where I'm at.

From other methods in the extending classes, `get_typed_ancestor()` is called to find the closest `_parent` of the class type to which that method belongs. This is better illustrated with an example; given the previous `AbstractNode` definition:

```
abstract class AbstractComplexNode extends AbstractNode{

    public function get_something(){
        if(something_exists()){
            return $something;
        }
        $node = $this->get_typed_ancestor();
        if(null !== $node){
            return $node->get_something();
        }
    }

}
```

The method `get_typed_ancestor()`, when called from the context of `AbstractComplexNode::get_something()`, will be looking for an object of type (*or extending type*) `AbstractComplexNode` -- in the case of this hierarchy, the possible concrete classes being `ComplexNodeOne` and `ComplexNodeTwo`.

Since `AbstractComplexNode` cannot be instantiated, a concrete instance such as `ComplexNodeOne` would be invoking `get_something()`.

**I need to highlight a point here;** the search in this previous case *must* be for `AbstractComplexNode` in order to find the first instance of either `ComplexNodeOne` or `ComplexNodeTwo`. As will be explained in a moment, searching for and `instanceof static` will fail, as it may skip instances of sibling classes and/or their children.

The **problem** is, since there are situations where the calling class is abstract, and the calling method is inherited by (*and thus is called from an instance of*) a class such as `ComplexNodeOne`, searching for a parent that is an [`instanceof`](http://ca.php.net/instanceof)[`static`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) doesn't work, as `static` is late-bound to the concrete `ComplexNodeOne`.

Now, I have a solution, but I don't like it:

```
abstract class AbstractNode{

    public function get_typed_ancestor($class){
        $node = $this;
        while(null !== $node->_parent){
            if($node->_parent instanceof $class){
                return $node->_parent;
            }
            $node = $node->_parent;
        }
        return null;
    }

}

abstract class AbstractComplexNode extends AbstractNode{

    public function get_something(){
        if(something_exists()){
            return $something;
        }
        $node = $this->get_typed_ancestor(__CLASS__);
        if(null !== $node){
            return $node->get_something();
        }
    }

}
```

This appears to work, since `__CLASS__` resolves to the class name of definition. Unfortunately, I tried using `__CLASS__` as a default argument to `get_typed_ancestor()` with no success (*though that was expected*)

I'm considering leaving the `$class` argument as an optional regardless, but if it is at all possible to "implicitly" pass this data along to the method (*in absence of the optional argument*) that would be great.

---

**Solutions/Failures**:

- Passing `__CLASS__` from the calling method as an argument to `get_typed_ancestor()`.
          Works, but is not ideal as I'd like `get_typed_ancestor()` to resolve the calling class without being explicitly informed of it.
- In the search loop, checking `if($node->_parent instanceof static)`.
          Doesn't work when the calling class inherits the calling method. It resolves to the concrete class in which the method is called, not the one in which is defined. This failure of course applies also to `self` and `parent`.
- Use `debug_backtrace()` to capture `$trace[1]['class']` and use that for the check.
          Works, but is not ideal as it's a hack.

<sub>It's tricky discussing a hierarchical data structure and supporting class hierarchy without feeling like you're confusing your audience.</sub>

---

**Example**:

```
abstract class AbstractNode
{
    protected $_id;

    protected $_parent;

    public function __construct($id, self $parent = null)
    {
        $this->_id = $id;
        if(null !== $parent)
        {
            $this->set_parent($parent);
        }
    }

    protected function get_typed_ancestor_by_class($class)
    {
        $node = $this;
        while(null !== $node->_parent)
        {
            if($node->_parent instanceof $class)
            {
                return $node->_parent;
            }
            $node = $node->_parent;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function get_typed_ancestor_with_static()
    {
        $node = $this;
        while(null !== $node->_parent)
        {
            if($node->_parent instanceof static)
            {
                return $node->_parent;
            }
            $node = $node->_parent;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function set_parent(self $parent)
    {
        $this->_parent = $parent;
    }

}

class SimpleNode extends AbstractNode
{

}

abstract class AbstractComplexNode extends AbstractNode
{

    public function test_method_class()
    {
        var_dump($this->get_typed_ancestor_by_class(__CLASS__));
    }

    public function test_method_static()
    {
        var_dump($this->get_typed_ancestor_with_static());
    }

}

class ComplexNodeOne extends AbstractComplexNode
{

}

class ComplexNodeTwo extends AbstractComplexNode
{

}

$node_1 = new SimpleNode(1);
$node_2 = new ComplexNodeTwo(2, $node_1);
$node_3 = new SimpleNode(3, $node_2);
$node_4 = new ComplexNodeOne(4, $node_3);
$node_5 = new SimpleNode(5, $node_4);
$node_6 = new ComplexNodeTwo(6, $node_5);

// this call incorrectly finds ComplexNodeTwo ($node_2), skipping
// the instance of ComplexNodeOne ($node_4)
$node_6->test_method_static();
//    object(ComplexNodeTwo)#2 (2) {
//      ["_id":protected]=>
//      int(2)
//      ["_parent":protected]=>
//      object(SimpleNode)#1 (2) {
//        ["_id":protected]=>
//        int(1)
//        ["_parent":protected]=>
//        NULL
//      }
//    }

// this call correctly finds ComplexNodeOne ($node_4) since it's
// looking for an instance of AbstractComplexNode, resolved from
// the passed __CLASS__
$node_6->test_method_class();
//    object(ComplexNodeOne)#4 (2) {
//      ["_id":protected]=>
//      int(4)
//      ["_parent":protected]=>
//      object(SimpleNode)#3 (2) {
//        ["_id":protected]=>
//        int(3)
//        ["_parent":protected]=>
//        object(ComplexNodeTwo)#2 (2) {
//          ["_id":protected]=>
//          int(2)
//          ["_parent":protected]=>
//          object(SimpleNode)#1 (2) {
//            ["_id":protected]=>
//            int(1)
//            ["_parent":protected]=>
//            NULL
//          }
//        }
//      }
//    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For solving the problem "*to capture the calling class of a given method or function*", simply pass the object that creates the instance in the constructor.

```
<?php

class A {
  public function caller() {
    $b = new B ($this);
    $b->bar();
  }
}

class B {
  $whoClass = '';
  public function __construct($who)
  {
    $this->whoClass = get_class($who);
  }
  public function bar($who) {
    echo get_class($this->whoClass);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is proper solution, not the reflection/backtrace insanity OP was considering. Using these heavy duty  cannons like that is a way to programmer's hell.

Comment: Thanks @macjohn -- Passing the context (*via `$this`*) won't exactly solve the problem. As in the case of my example, if an instance of `ComplexNodeOne` is passed, the retrieved class will be just that. What I'm after is, if I call a method that has been *inherited* by `ComplexNodeOne` (*defined in `AbstractComplexNode`*) the class retrieved should be `AbstractComplexNode`, not the class of the instance of `$this`. This will allow the search to find any instance derived from `AbstractComplexNode` and not just another instance of the concrete context object.