# Possible poor design; forcing static definition in inheriting classes in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, static

I think I may have hit a wall due to poor design decisions.

I'm working on a class hierarchy, with an abstract base from which a few classes extend. Without getting into the "nitty-gritty" of why, the function of instances of these classes require that a "context" object be available -- the currently operating object.

```
abstract class AbstractBase{

    protected static $_context;

    protected $_parent;

    public static function get_context(){
        return static::$_context;
    }

    protected static function set_context(self $context, &$previous = null){
        $previous = static::get_context();
        static::$_context = $context;
    }

    public function __construct(){
        $this->_parent = static::get_context();
    }

    public function do_something($callback){
        static::set_context($this, $previous);
        $callback();
        static::set_context($previous);
    }

}

class ConcreteOne extends AbstractBase{

}

class ConcreteTwo extends AbstractBase{

}
```

This works fine, except that `ConcreteOne` and `ConcreteTwo` need to keep track of their own context -- the current definition will cause any context change from any inheriting class to overwrite `AbstractBase::$_context`. This change is reasonably easy to implement:

```
class ConcreteOne extends AbstractBase{

    protected static $_context;

}

class ConcreteTwo extends AbstractBase{

    protected static $_context;

}
```

Now the concrete implementations will manage their own contexts. This however presents a bit of an issue; any client classes extending the base class will have the requirement of a static member named `$_context`.

This stinks of bad design to me, but then again, my nose isn't the sharpest yet. I'm wondering if I've moseyed down a bad path here, and most importantly, if I should continue down said path or abort and change it up.

So, should I forge ahead, or can someone suggest a better solution to managing a "static" context across instances?

---

**Note**: I've considered passing the `$context` object as an argument to the `$callback`, however since `ConcreteOne` callbacks may create instances of, and call, `ConcreteTwo` objects (*and vice versa, and any other inheriting class*) that could result in a great number of context objects needing to be passed around at a given time -- I don't think that's a solution.

Comment: I wonder if you could use a hash table within the `$_context`, and then when you create the object that extends `AbstractBase`, make a unique id for that object and store it's context in the static `$_context` with that id as the key. That way you don't need a `$_context` in the extended classes. I keep thinking this is a type of a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but I can't decide if it is or not.

Comment: Maybe something along these lines: http://codepad.org/1FlYkTN1

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish -- It's not a singleton pattern; the objects can be instantiated ad infinitum. When the `do_something()` method is invoked however, the "context" changes to that object, so that objects created within the passed `$callback` will have that context if they are of the same type. The "*same type*" caveat is what's posing the problem here. I keep changing gears in development, thankfully there is no existing project so I'm free to change anything -- I've posted another question previously, somewhat related to this topic http://stackoverflow.com/q/8425752/409279.

Comment: @JaredFarrish -- Comment posted before your codepad; interesting approach. I'm reading around for solutions and many seem to use something similar, registering objects with a GUID for retrieval, rather than relying on the OOP paradigm to manage it inherently.

Comment: The singleton reference had to do with `$_context`, since it's pointing to a single store; it doesn't fit exactly, but kind've. The reason it works is that you have the `static $_context` declared in the abstract class, but you also have the local-to-the-object `private $id`. It is icky to think you'd have an abstract `$_context` AND a class-specific `$_context` (what's the abstract one for, don't forget to copy it down into the class... It's problematic) to make it work. This is cleaner and easier to understand (and DRY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and post this as an answer, since I believe this is what you are working towards in the end.

The problem I believe you're spotting is that you have the abstract class property `$_context`, which is setup to store a single context, yet to make it work right, you're really needing a reference within/by the actual class itself. So the `$_context` property, in your example, is actually a reference to the current object's context, NOT a single context for all instantiated classes that extend your `AbstractBase`.

This, of course, doesn't make sense. What I would suggest is a tweak to your current static `$_context` and use it as a store to save and retrieve your references, returning a unique ID when the context is set and putting that ID into a `$this->context_id` so the object can continue to get it's context by reference:

```
<?php

abstract class AbstractBase {
    protected static $_context;
    private $context_id;

    public static function setContext($context) {
        $context_id = uniqid(php_uname('n'), true);
        self::$_context[$context_id] = $context;
        return $context_id;
    }

    public function getContext() {
        return self::$_context[$this->context_id];
    }

    public function myPrint() {
        print_r($this);
        print_r(self::$_context);
    }
}

class test1 extends AbstractBase {
    public function __construct($context){
        $this->context_id = self::setContext($context);
    }
}

class test2 extends AbstractBase {
    public function __construct($context){
        $this->context_id = self::setContext($context);
    }
}

$test1 = new test1('this stuff');
$test2 = new test2('other stuff');

$test1->myPrint();
$test2->myPrint();

?>
```

http://codepad.org/1FlYkTN1

Comment: Thanks @JaredFarrish -- Definitely seems like the most appropriate solution so far. I'm dying (*5:19am*) so I believe I'll start fresh tomorrow on some test cases. +1 for sure, possible accept in the morning (*later in the morning I suppose*) Based on your approach, I'm also concocting a similar solution that leverages `SplObjectStorage`, we'll see where it goes.

Comment: I like the elegance of being able to handle the entire context with the abstract class-defined methods and properties. Another approach that occurs to me is to have a `ConcreteTypes` object to store and handle your instantiated objects, including the context management. It would just depend on what you're doing, since this could potentially be much more complicated, but it would be on it's face possibly more self-descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

This does look a bit forced. I think a 'regular' base class that has static methods - or having a static object would be a better strategy.

Comment: Thanks @matthijs koevoets -- Care to elaborate a bit? When you say "regular" base class, do you mean one with no knowledge of "context"?